# Error creando triggers con dbvisualizer

Tags: sql, trigger

Estoy usando la versión de **DbVisualizer Pro 9.5.6** y estoy ejecutando el siguiente comando `sql` para crear `triggers`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MYDB"."TG_T01_01" BEFORE INSERT ON T01
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
                :NEW.FECALT_01 := SYSDATE;
                :NEW.FECMOD_01 := SYSDATE;                    
                SELECT T01Q00.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID_01 FROM DUAL;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MYDB"."TG_T01_02" 
BEFORE UPDATE ON T01
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
                :NEW.FECMOD_01 := SYSDATE;                
END;
/...
```

Son una serie de `triggers` idénticos de las distintas tablas de la BBDD. Cuando ejecuto el comando `sql` me muestra estos mensajes de error:

> 14:42:07  [CREATE - 0 rows, 0.032 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
>
> 14:42:07  [:NEW.USUMOD_01 - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  Tipo SQL no válido: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
>
> 14:42:07  [END - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: sentencia SQL no válida
>
> 14:42:07  [/ - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: sentencia SQL no válida
>
> 14:42:07  [:NEW.FECMOD_01 - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  Tipo SQL no válido: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
>
> 14:42:07  [:NEW.USUALT_01 - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  Tipo SQL no válido: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
>
> 14:42:07  [:NEW.USUMOD_01 - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  Tipo SQL no válido: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
>
> 14:42:07  [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 1008, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-01008: no todas las variables han sido enlazadas
>
> 14:42:07  [END - 0 rows, 0.015 secs]  [Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: sentencia SQL no válida
>
> ...

Despues de esto se crea un `trigger` de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MYDB"."TG_T01_01" BEFORE INSERT ON T01
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
                    :NEW.FECALT_01 := SYSDATE
```

**Nota:** El `trigger` que se ha creado de manera errónea se puede editar y poner el código, de tal manera que el `trigger` si que funciona y el código esta bien escrito, así que he concluido que lo mas probable es que el interprete `sql` de **DbVisualizer** considere a los `;` como un `END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución mas sencilla para mi en este caso ha sido instalarme Oracle SQL Developer y ejecutar la consulta, aunque me gustaría saber porque DbVisualizer no podía ejecutar la sql.